# Could not find Android SDK after reopening eclipse

Tags: android

I have installed all the requirements for eclipse and installed Android SDK and run it. It was working fine, but when I again open eclipse in preference, it shows no target available, means no SDK installed. But it is indeed installed in C folder.

Comment: set android sdk path in eclipse

Comment: please use Android studio. Eclipse support is stopped officially.

Comment: Thanks.I am installing android studio as my friend also suggest this.shall i have to download new JDK and SDK ??or any video tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Please set android sdk path 
Eclipse->Window->Preferences-> select Android from left hand menu-> There you should see option to set SDK path[image]

Comment: i have done all these process and also run my program 1 time but after that "no SDK location found".